# invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel by running sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox, dkms

I am trying to execute the **vagrant up** command in Ubuntu. After some recommendations here on StackOverflow, I tried running other commands to try and solve this, but now I'm stuck and I don't know what I should do. This is what I have done until now.

Step 1:

```
$ vagrant up

No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

Step 2:

```
$ vagrant up --provider virtualbox
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'ServerSHARK' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

Step 3:

```
$ VBoxManage --version
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
         Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
         headers, most likely linux-headers-standard.

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.1.32_Ubuntur149290
```

Step 4:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
virtualbox-dkms is already the newest version (6.1.32-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1).
virtualbox-dkms set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp javascript-common libauthen-sasl-perl libc-ares2 libdata-dump-perl
  libencode-locale-perl libfile-basedir-perl libfile-desktopentry-perl
  libfile-listing-perl libfile-mimeinfo-perl libfont-afm-perl libhtml-form-perl
  libhtml-format-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-tree-perl
  libhttp-cookies-perl libhttp-daemon-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl
  libhttp-negotiate-perl libio-html-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl libio-stringy-perl
  libipc-system-simple-perl libjs-inherits libjs-is-typedarray libjs-psl
  libjs-typedarray-to-buffer liblwp-mediatypes-perl liblwp-protocol-https-perl
  libmailtools-perl libnet-dbus-perl libnet-http-perl libnet-smtp-ssl-perl
  libnet-ssleay-perl libtie-ixhash-perl libtimedate-perl libtry-tiny-perl
  liburi-perl libuv1-dev libwww-perl libwww-robotrules-perl libx11-protocol-perl
  libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml-xpathengine-perl node-abbrev
  node-ajv node-ansi node-ansi-align node-ansi-regex node-ansi-styles
  node-ansistyles node-aproba node-archy node-are-we-there-yet node-asap
  node-asn1 node-assert-plus node-asynckit node-aws-sign2 node-aws4
  node-balanced-match node-bcrypt-pbkdf node-bl node-bluebird node-boxen
  node-brace-expansion node-builtin-modules node-builtins node-cacache
  node-call-limit node-camelcase node-caseless node-chalk node-chownr
  node-ci-info node-cli-boxes node-cliui node-clone node-co node-color-convert
  node-color-name node-colors node-columnify node-combined-stream node-concat-map
  node-concat-stream node-config-chain node-configstore
  node-console-control-strings node-copy-concurrently node-core-util-is
  node-cross-spawn node-crypto-random-string node-cyclist node-dashdash
  node-debug node-decamelize node-decompress-response node-deep-extend
  node-defaults node-define-properties node-delayed-stream node-delegates
  node-detect-indent node-detect-newline node-dot-prop node-duplexer3
  node-duplexify node-ecc-jsbn node-editor node-encoding node-end-of-stream
  node-err-code node-errno node-es6-promise node-escape-string-regexp node-execa
  node-extend node-extsprintf node-fast-deep-equal node-find-up
  node-flush-write-stream node-forever-agent node-form-data node-from2
  node-fs-vacuum node-fs-write-stream-atomic node-fs.realpath node-function-bind
  node-gauge node-genfun node-get-caller-file node-get-stream node-getpass
  node-glob node-got node-graceful-fs node-har-schema node-har-validator
  node-has-flag node-has-symbol-support-x node-has-to-string-tag-x
  node-has-unicode node-hosted-git-info node-http-signature node-iconv-lite
  node-iferr node-import-lazy node-imurmurhash node-inflight node-inherits
  node-ini node-invert-kv node-ip node-ip-regex node-is-npm node-is-obj
  node-is-object node-is-path-inside node-is-plain-obj node-is-retry-allowed
  node-is-stream node-is-typedarray node-isarray node-isexe node-isstream
  node-isurl node-jsbn node-json-parse-better-errors node-json-schema
  node-json-schema-traverse node-json-stable-stringify node-json-stringify-safe
  node-jsonify node-jsonparse node-jsonstream node-jsprim node-latest-version
  node-lazy-property node-lcid node-libnpx node-locate-path node-lockfile
  node-lodash node-lodash-packages node-lowercase-keys node-lru-cache
  node-make-dir node-mem node-mime node-mime-types node-mimic-fn
  node-mimic-response node-minimatch node-minimist node-mississippi node-mkdirp
  node-move-concurrently node-ms node-mute-stream node-nopt
  node-normalize-package-data node-npm-bundled node-npm-package-arg
  node-npm-run-path node-npmlog node-number-is-nan node-oauth-sign
  node-object-assign node-once node-opener node-os-locale node-os-tmpdir
  node-osenv node-p-cancelable node-p-finally node-p-is-promise node-p-limit
  node-p-locate node-p-timeout node-package-json node-parallel-transform
  node-path-exists node-path-is-absolute node-path-is-inside node-performance-now
  node-pify node-prepend-http node-process-nextick-args node-promise-inflight
  node-promise-retry node-promzard node-proto-list node-prr node-pseudomap
  node-psl node-pump node-pumpify node-punycode node-qs node-qw node-rc node-read
  node-read-package-json node-readable-stream node-registry-auth-token
  node-registry-url node-request node-require-directory
  node-require-main-filename node-resolve node-resolve-from node-retry
  node-rimraf node-run-queue node-safe-buffer node-semver node-semver-diff
  node-set-blocking node-sha node-shebang-command node-shebang-regex
  node-signal-exit node-slash node-slide node-sorted-object node-spdx-correct
  node-spdx-exceptions node-spdx-expression-parse node-spdx-license-ids
  node-sshpk node-ssri node-stream-each node-stream-iterate node-stream-shift
  node-strict-uri-encode node-string-decoder node-string-width node-strip-ansi
  node-strip-eof node-strip-json-comments node-supports-color node-tar
  node-term-size node-text-table node-through node-through2 node-timed-out
  node-tough-cookie node-tunnel-agent node-tweetnacl node-typedarray
  node-typedarray-to-buffer node-uid-number node-unique-filename
  node-unique-string node-unpipe node-uri-js node-url-parse-lax
  node-url-to-options node-util-deprecate node-uuid
  node-validate-npm-package-license node-validate-npm-package-name node-verror
  node-wcwidth.js node-which node-which-module node-wide-align node-widest-line
  node-wrap-ansi node-wrappy node-write-file-atomic node-xdg-basedir node-xtend
  node-y18n node-yallist node-yargs node-yargs-parser perl-openssl-defaults
  x11-xserver-utils xdg-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
```

Step 5: This is where I got stuck. None of the tips seem to help.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms
    
    -------- Uninstall Beginning --------
    Module:  virtualbox
    Version: 6.1.32
    Kernel:  5.4.0-120-generic (x86_64)
    -------------------------------------
    
    Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.
    
    vboxdrv.ko:
     - Uninstallation
       - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-120-generic/updates/dkms/
     - Original module
       - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
       - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
    
    
    vboxnetadp.ko:
     - Uninstallation
       - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-120-generic/updates/dkms/
     - Original module
       - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
       - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
    
    
    vboxnetflt.ko:
     - Uninstallation
       - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.4.0-120-generic/updates/dkms/
     - Original module
       - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
       - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.
    
    depmod...
    
    DKMS: uninstall completed.
    
    ------------------------------
    Deleting module version: 6.1.32
    completely from the DKMS tree.
    ------------------------------
    Done.
    Loading new virtualbox-6.1.32 DKMS files...
    It is likely that 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 belongs to a chroot's host
    Building for 5.4.0-120-generic
    Building initial module for 5.4.0-120-generic
    Done.
    
    vboxdrv.ko:
    Running module version sanity check.
     - Original module
       - No original module exists within this kernel
     - Installation
       - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-120-generic/updates/dkms/
    
    vboxnetadp.ko:
    Running module version sanity check.
     - Original module
       - No original module exists within this kernel
     - Installation
       - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-120-generic/updates/dkms/
    
    vboxnetflt.ko:
    Running module version sanity check.
     - Original module
       - No original module exists within this kernel
     - Installation
       - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-120-generic/updates/dkms/
    
    depmod...
    
    DKMS: install completed.
    invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
```

Same with this:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
```

Am I overseeing something? Maybe I'm not seeing the right problem.
Thanks for your help!